# ADOM Village dungeon does not contain 7 levels

Tags: adom

[image]

This is level 4 of the village dungeon. I've never managed to go deeper than it because the way is blocked. Sometimes, there is a priest, sometimes not.
How can I go further?

Comment: Right where you are is a secret door.  Hit W, then S.  Repeat until you find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means the rest of the level is behind a secret door. You can always try <kbd>s</kbd>earching (hit <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to search for several turns) surrounding squares or <kbd>k</kbd>icking walls until you find something.

Unless/until you have some other means to get clues on where the door is, you'll have to guess or rely on your understanding of the game's random level generation algorithm to find the right spot.